# How to convert ilike to full text search in Postgres 9.1+

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, tsvector

Shopping cart uses following query for searching products:

```
select ...
from toode,yksus7,artliik,artryhm
where toode.nimetus ilike '%'||{{5}}||'%' escape '!' 
      or toode.toode ilike '%'||{{5}}||'%' escape '!' 
      or toode.analoog ilike '%'||{{5}}||'%' escape '!' 
      or yksus7.nimetus ilike '%'||{{5}}||'%' escape '!' 
      or artliik.artlnimi ilike '%'||{{5}}||'%' escape '!' 
      or artryhm.nimetus ilike '%'||{{5}}||'%' escape '!' 
      or toode.markused ilike '%'||{{5}}||'%' escape '!'
...
```

search field types are character(n) and TEXT
`{{5}}` represents search term entered by user into search box in web page.

This query words only exact matches. 
Texts from diffrent tables `toode,yksus7,artliik,artryhm` joined in WHERE clause needs searched and best matching results returned.

If User types

```
blank pencil
```

query does not found records containing text with words not ix exact order like

```
pencil black
```

How to fix this so that similar results are also returned ?
PostgreSql versions starting from  9.1 are used.

Comment: There is pretty good documentation about full text search [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html).

Comment: I used `WHERE to_tsvector('english',toode.nimetus) @@
       array_to_string((string_to_array({{5}}, ' '))[1:99], ' & ') ::tsquery or ...` is this OK ?

Comment: `plainto_tsquery` is simpler. Of course queries with `OR` are never efficient; consider using `UNION`.

Comment: I changed it to `to_tsvector('english',toode.nimetus) @@ plainto_tsquery({{8}})` and created index `create index toode_nimetus_fts_idx on toode USING gin(to_tsvector('english', nimetus))` . Is this OK. Will this index used for search

Comment: Should work. Try with `EXPLAIN` to be sure.